# Collections: Interfaces and Classes

Tags: java, collections, interface

When coding with Collections:

Why use:

```
List<String> mList= new ArrayList<String>();
```

Why not:

```
ArrayList<String> mList=new ArrayList<String>();
```

When I ask the answer is : *"It is JAVA convention".*

I need a comprehensive, logical and expressive answer on this.

Comment: Eh, it is just a convention.  Either one works, but it's a layer of abstraction, so that if you decide to change the type of list (`List mList = new LinkedList()`), you can do so without messing up any other references.

Comment: So you can change the List implementation if you decide to later without changing other code

Comment: But in this case, The Array List must be having some more methods, additional to the List interface, Doesn't this way of programming eliminates me to use those additional features if any.

Comment: @PuneetSahota Any additional features should be exposed through a subinterface, e.g. `List` extending `Collection`.

Comment: I am still confused as to why we need to use an Interface reference when we can use a class reference, i apologize for the inconvenivnce, i am new to JAVA so understanding some things takes time for me.

Comment: You don't **need** to.  If you do it the other way it works fine.  It is literally just a convention; you can choose to do either but most people use `List` only.